# Fetching data from has_one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, has-one

I have this models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :page, dependent: :destroy

end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :infos, :title, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

end
```

in the page index view, when I do

```
<%= page.user.name  %>
```

I can get the value, but in the user page view, when I do

```
<%= user.page %>
```

I get the object: `#<Page:0x000000045a0470>`

and when I do `<%= user.page.title %>` I get the error: **undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass**

how can I do to get the values from has_many model in the right way?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:

Not all users has a page, so I do this:

change

```
<%= user.page.title %>
```

to

```
<%= user.page.try(:title) %>
```

Then it fix the error. =D